# Neo4j query execution time

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

How to get exact neo4j query execution time. I used PROFILE where its shows below information in the neo4j browser.

[image]

Is this the right execution time? Also can someone direct me how to read PROFILE details?

Where I can find good example for optimizing neo4j query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use the Desktop to execute a Cypher query, the bottom of the result panel will display some statistics, including how long it took to start streaming the results (which indicates how long it took to get the results) and how long it took to finish streaming the results.

   For example:

   > Added 91 labels, created 91 nodes, set 259
   >   properties, started streaming 1 records after 44 ms and completed
   >   after 44 ms.
2. You can find detailed documentation for Cypher execution plans [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/execution-plans/).